# Which kanji writing should i follow when writing on paper, digital or non-digital?

Tags: orthography, handwriting

I have came across 必 and wanted to learn how to write it. Though there are major differences between how it looks digitally and how it looks on paper. Here is the link I used : http://jisho.org/search/%E5%BF%85%20%23kanji

Which one should I follow when writing on paper?

Comment: How are they different in your view?  To my eyes, they look virtually the same, the main difference being the third stroke...  Is that what you are asking about?

Comment: "Which one should I follow when writing on paper, how it looks digitally and how it looks on paper?" -- The latter, I guess? でもまず「心」から練習してみたら・・筆順違うけど

Answer (score 2):

When you practice writing kanji, use the form in the video or under "stroke order".

Typical Japanese serif fonts are called 明朝体, and sans-serif fonts are called ゴシック体. They are very common, but do not necessarily reflect how you should write characters by hand. (By the way, this is not specific to Japanese; many English serif fonts use "[double-story g](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/G#Typographic_variants)", which is not what people typically write by hand.)

There is a font called 教科書体 (literally "textbook font"), which is used in children's textbooks and reflects how people should handwrite characters. For more information, see: [Is there an "official" font or other writing standard that should be used when teaching kanji?](https://japanese.stackexchange.com/q/18782/5010)

[image]